# Python Pandas concat stock data returns NaN values instead

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pandas-datareader

I am working on a Python Pandas project and got stuck with concat part.
Basically, I have retrieved stock data as following

```
df = data.DataReader(['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC'],'morningstar',start,end)
```

head shows this:
[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdhgf.png)

Then I use `pd.concat()` to join them, and add the column names with the following

```
bank_stocks = pd.concat([BAC,C,GS,JPM,MS,WF],axis=1,keys=tickers)
bank_stocks.columns.names = ['Bank Ticker','Stock Info']
```

but when I look at `bank_stocks.head()` I have many NaN values:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwGgk.png)

what I need to get is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laLFv.png)

It might be something very simple, but being a rookie I can't figure it out by myself.
Anyone can give me hand out please? Thank you.

Comment: try removing the symbol from index - also post the data in the question not pictures.

Comment: Take your df from your df.head() and unstack level zero, then pd.concat those dataframes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your concat statement. You need to pass individual data frames that you wish concatenated. As per your requirement you need to concatenate information for each ticker, so each ticker represents a data-frame that needs to be concatenated.

The correct syntax would be:
    `pd.concat([df.loc['BAC'],df.loc['C'],df.loc['GS'],df.loc['JPM'],df.loc['MS'],df.loc'WF']],axis=1,keys=tickers)`

I believe `tickers` is defined in your program as some list containing all the ticker symbols.